# USB Microphone not working with Zoom in raspberry pi

Tags: usb, pulseaudio, microphone, raspberrypi, zoom-meeting

I've installed pi-apps in my daughters Raspberry pi 400, and successfully installed Zoom. Everything works fine, we are able to connect to meeting, the video works fine, there is a little lag, but nothing that wouldn't make impossible to use. The only exception is the input sound. The Rapsberry pi 400 has no sound jack, so we are using a USB camera with integrated mic. The mic works fine elsewhere, both in a mic test within Raspberry pi 400, and on a PC, but on Zoom it doesn't work properly. For the initial seconds it works fine, but after that it only really registers loud sounds and even those not properly. For example if one claps, the other side will only hear light "tick tick". Am I missing installing something? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Make and model of the camera? Have you looked to see if the camera has a Ubuntu driver? What version of Ubuntu are you running and what kernel?

Comment: i am using linux based raspberry pi